# Handling a slow-loading webpage removing hardcoded delay from my script

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I've written a script in python in association with selenium to parse some names from a webpage handling the lazyloading method for which the webpage displays it's content upon each scroll to the bottom. My script does it errorlessly. However, the only issue I can't resolve is take out hardcoded delay from my script. I really can't find any idea as to how I can use `explicit wait` instead of `hardcoded delay` keeping the logic (applied within the script) as it is to make it more efficient. Thanks in advance for any help.

[Webpage link](https://www.yellowpages.ca/search/si/1/coffee/all%20states)

This is what I've tried so far (working one):

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("find_the_link_above")

last_len = len(driver.find_elements_by_class_name("listing__name--link"))
new_len = last_len

while True:
    last_len = new_len
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

    time.sleep(3) ##I wish to kick out this harcoded delay and use explicit wait in place

    items = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("listing__name--link")
    new_len = len(items)
    if last_len == new_len:break

for item in items:
    print(item.text)
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way how you can implement ExplicitWait:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.yellowpages.ca/search/si/1/coffee/all%20states")

last_len = len(driver.find_elements_by_class_name("listing__name--link"))

while True:
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    try:
        wait(driver, 3).until(lambda driver: len(driver.find_elements_by_class_name("listing__name--link")) > last_len)
        items = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("listing__name--link")
        last_len = len(items)
    except TimeoutException:
        break

for item in items:
    print(item.text)
driver.quit()
```

This should allow you to scroll down and wait up to 3 seconds (increase timeout if needed) until elements number increased in a loop or break the `while` loop in case the number remains the same

Answer (score 0):

To parse the names from the [webpage](https://www.yellowpages.ca/search/si/1/coffee/all%20states) you can use the following code block :

- *Code Block* :

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

  items = []

  options = Options()
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
  options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
  options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get('https://www.yellowpages.ca/search/si/1/coffee/all%20states')
  items=driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("h3[itemprop='name']>a.listing__name--link")
  while(driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")):
      items.append(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("h3[itemprop='name']>a.listing__name--link"))
  for item in items:
      print(item.text)
  ```
- *Console Output* :

  ```
  Tim Hortons
  Downtown Expresso Café
  Tim Hortons
  Tim Hortons
  Tim Hortons
  Starbucks
  Tim Hortons
  Tim Hortons
  Tim Hortons
  Tim Hortons
  Tim Hortons
  Tim Hortons
  Tim Hortons
  Starbucks
  Tim Hortons
  Tim Hortons
  Budokan
  Anchor Cafe House
  Starbucks
  Tim Hortons
  Tim Hortons
  Starbucks
  Tim Hortons
  Starbucks
  Tim Hortons
  Tim Hortons
  Colonial Coffee Co Ltd
  Personal Service Coffee
  Tim Hortons
  Suzie's Grill Cafe Inc
  Loaves N Fishes Catering & Cafe
  Tim Hortons
  Tim Hortons
  Tim Hortons
  Tim Hortons
  Elizabeth Houte Coiffure
  The Grind House Cafe
  Tim Hortons
  Black Bench Coffee Roasters
  Tim Hortons
  ```

Comment: My existing script is giving me 127 names (all the name) whereas your suggested script is giving me first 40 results. The way I tried above sometimes becomes inconsistent because of the hard-coded delay. However, twitching the delay I can always get right results. So, I'm after all the results without using hardcoded delay not the first few results. Thanks.